# A simple STL based Undirected graph implementation in C++

Tags: c++, stl

Libraries like [Boost](http://boost.org) or [SNAP](http://snap.stanford.edu) provide graph data structures but are quite complicated. I am new to C++ STL and looking for a simple Adjacency List based undirected graph representation. Googling got me nothing thats fits the bill. However, this problem seems quite standard and I think I can skip reinventing the wheel for my project.

Comment: Check out codereview.stackexchange.com, you'll find a lot of examples, often of a great quality.

Comment: when dealing with C++  everything is complicated :) LOL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C++ on its own, doesn't offer any `graph` class that you might use. If you don't want to reinvent the wheel (which is a good thing), the only way to achieve what you wish is using an additional library.

If you need something simple, maybe using `std::map` could suffice. If you need something more advanced, try:

```
template <typename key_type, typename val_type>
class graph{
   std::map<key_type,val_type> nodes;
   std::set<std::pair<key_type,key_type> > connections;
};
```